# How to increase the allowed number of API calls?

Tags: support, api, rate-limit, quota

Stack Exchange provides the possibility to do a limited number of API calls per day from the same IP (10,000 if the customer registers the app).

Is it possible to get that number increased?

Answer (score 1):

See [the *Throttles* doc page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle).

The 10K limit is not if the *customer* registers, it is if ***you*** register your app and provide the key when you make API calls.

Also, you can get more than 10K per IP if your app authenticates the user and then passes a valid `access_token`.  In that case, it becomes 10K per logged in user and does not share the 10K IP limit.

From the doc:

> If an application does have an access_token, then the application is on a distinct user/app pair daily quota (default size of 10,000). A user can have up to 5 distinct quotas at any one time, though this limit is not reflected in quota_remaining returns for privacy reasons.

---

If you need more than 10K, per app, calls; chances are that you are doing something inefficiently.

**Do you have a specific example, or is this just a hypothetical?**

If you can **point to a specific, legit app** that is being crippled by the 10K quota, then chances are pretty good that people will either point out how it could be done in a less intensive way, or Stack Exchange could be persuaded to adjust the quota (They're often pretty good about such things).

Comment: Thanks Brock, pretty helpful! Yes, I meant the same like you saying "The 10K limit is not if the customer registers". Regarding specific example: no,I do not have such yet, I'm about to develop a simple app that would make a REST calls, so I'm interested in max number of allowed API calls, just to be sure that numbers won't be reached.

Comment: If you mean that it would be making multiple calls to get the same resources over time it should be pointed out that the site uses a lot of caching, and therefore they suggest you not even bother requesting the same resource more then once per minute because it probably hasn't changed. (Last paragraph of https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle). That works out to 1440 useful calls on the same resource per day.